# RJ45 Magjack connection

Tags: circuit-analysis, component-selection

my doubt

1. TXP,TXN of phy chip is connecting to P1 and P3 of the connector.
2. I thought it must connect to P4 and P6 of the connector.

Can somebody please let me know which is correct point 1 or 2 ?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the LAN8710A:

TXP connects to TD+ (pin 1 of the MagJack)

TXN connects to TD- (pin 3 of the MagJack)

RXP connects to RD+ (pin 4)

RXN connects to RD- (pin 6)

So your schematic looks to be correct.